# Microcontroller : measure voltage with adc

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, batteries, adc

[image]I have 36 battery cells in series with voltage range from 0V to 1.6V and i want to monitor the voltage of these cells with a microcontroller (part of a battery management system).
So can you give me an idea on how i can make a circuit in which i can measure the voltage of 36 cells with 1 microcontroller ( maybe using voltage comparator and mux).

EDIT: i'm working on a battery management system based on inductor charge transfert between cells so can i use voltage comparator like that to measure the voltage ?

Comment: So what have you already tried? Do you have a design in mind that you want feedback on?

Comment: actually i want a suggest first on how i can make this happen

Comment: That's not what this site is for. You're supposed to show that you've made an attempt; EE.SE isn't a free design service.

Comment: sorry if you misunderstanded me but i didn't say i want a hole design just an idea how i can do this if possible and of course i'll start working on the idea and developing more. the problem here is the high number of adc input needed in the microcontroller first and i'm thinking on using a voltage comparator to have the voltage of each cell independent

Comment: 36 of those batteries in series is 576 volts, way to much for any logic IC's. You will need 36 small DPDT PCB mount relays made by Omron. They have 1 amp contacts which is good enough to read the voltage and provide a charging voltage < 1 amp. This circuit MUST be isolated from the batteries, and sample/charge only one at a time.

Comment: actually the voltage is 36*1.6V = 57.6V yes it's still too much for IC's but i'm planning on measuring voltage of each cell one by one ( from 0V to 1.6V ) which is in the range of any adc in a microcontroller

Comment: It would be easier to measure the 57.6V using a two resistor voltage divider.  If you can waste a few µA of the battery.

Comment: Get a 36-input analog multiplexor, and use the 10bit ADC in the MCU to measure each of the cells. Are these cells in series?  The total voltage will be higher than most analog multiplexors can handle.

Answer (score 1):

Monitoring all 36 cells individually with a single MCU A/D converter will take some serious design work with very careful attention to isolation and high common mode voltages.

This site is not a design service that will give you a detailed suggestion of how this can be done but there is one relatively simple architecture that can allow individual cell monitoring to occur. The safest scheme is to temporarily remove each cell in turn from the stack-up and connect it to the monitoring system. This can be done using the following general wiring scheme and requiring a small DPDT relay per cell.

[image]

The relay provides the isolation and temporary removal of each cell from the stack. There needs to be a separate circuit to provide for the drive to each relay coil. The design needs to comprehend that only one relay may be activated at a time.

This scheme depends upon the need for the relay driver subsystem and the cell monitoring subsystem to be powered from a source separate from the battery stack.

You can argue all day long that this solution is too expensive or complex for your needs. But you asked for ideas and here this one sits.

Comment: There needs to be a bypass diode per each cell so when it is being measured or charged the current can still flow through the other 35 batteries. +1 for posting what I commented about.

Comment: Adding the bypass diode is another diode option. That option would only be needed if you wanted the remaining battery stack to provide power to something whilst the monitoring was taking place.

Comment: In previous comment I tried to say "Adding the bypass diode is another design option.".

Answer (score 1):

Modern electronic industry is not up to handling 60-volt batteries in one unit yet. Best analog muxes (Vishay DG408) can handle only up to 44 V. Then a diff amp should be that handles 60V common mode, which is not easy. So your task sounds like very challenging.

The automotive industry does it by smaller sections, and merge the result via opto-isolators. Here is one solution from [NEC/Renesas](https://www.renesas.com/en-us/solutions/automotive/hev-ev/battery-control.html):

[image]

Comment: This is the industry standard method afik. There are many off the shelf battery monitoring ICs that can be used like this.